10" homelab server rack with open back
I want to start with upgrading my homelab. With this upgrade I want to get everything in one  rack. This will be my fist server rack so I don't know what can fit so preferably I want to buy everything by one company. I have at the moment a Cisco router, Switch, couple of Raspberry Pi's and Nvidia Jetson nano's. Just to be save I want the server rack to have a open back (just to be save for the depth and easy access) if something like that exist. Everything should be able to fit in 6U 10" rack (little bit taller rack is also OK). I need to be able to buy optional items like mounting plates for my router, switch and SBC's.
